# Formula calculations in JQuery and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, excel, excel-formula

Formula:

```
(((A+(2*B))^(3/2))/((C+(2*D))^(3/2)))*(E-F)
```

Here i am passing  A=2, B=2, C=3, D=4, E=10, F=5
I have done this with `eval(formula)` in `JQuery` and `C#`, but not working. It's returning different result compare to `EXCEL`.
Can you please help me out to achieve this?

Comment: you can try my plugin here https://github.com/xsanisty/jquery-calx , but it require you to set some data before evaluating the formula, also the cell address need to be A1, B2, etc

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with this that will cause C# and JavaScript to return different results.

First, C# will treat both of those `(3/2)` sections as integer division, giving `1`.  JavaScript will give the expected result of `1.5`.

The other, main problem is the `^` operator.  In C# and JavaScript this is a boolean exclusive-or operation, in Excel it is an exponentiation operation.  Instead of raising the result of `A + (2 * B)` to the `1.5`th power, it will perform an XOR operation, converting both sides to integer and flipping the low bit.

The equivalent expression for JavaScript is:

```
Math.pow(A + 2 * B, 1.5) / Math.pow(C + 2 * D, 1.5) * (E - F)
```

For C# the only difference is the capitalization:

```
Math.Pow(A + 2 * B, 1.5) / Math.Pow(C + 2 * D, 1.5) * (E - F)
```

Whether your C# expression evaluator can handle that is the next question.

Comment: Thank you Corey. Here problem is i am getting that actual  formula from database. I need arrange like what you suggested (Math.pow(A + 2 * B, 1.5) / Math.pow(C + 2 * D, 1.5) * (E - F)). Do we have any plugin to return the result based on formula. Suppose if changed the formula in future, it would be a problem.